# C# folderbrowser dialog problem

Tags: c#

I have a button that once clicked uses a stremReader to read a text file, and a folderbrowser dialog to save a file. Once I save the file and and click on the button again I get an error saying it cannot find the text file, and it tries to read the the text file from the path where the previous document was saved.

Is there any way I can resolve this problem?

Here is a part of the code:

```
private void Invoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"../../DatabasePath");
        dataBase = sr.ReadLine();

        if (dataBase == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please use this to choose the location of the database.");
            Process.Start(@"..\..\DatabaseChooser.exe");
            ready = false;
        }

        if (!ready)
        {
            while (IsProcessOpen("DatabaseChooser"))
            {
                ready = false;
            }
            ready = true;

            if (ready)
            {
                doIfReady();
            }
        }

        else if (ready)
        {
            doIfReady();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void btnCreateInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int SelectColumnIndex = 5;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewInvoice.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[SelectColumnIndex].Value != null &&
               Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[SelectColumnIndex].Value) == true)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.OwningColumn.Index != SelectColumnIndex)
                {
                    data += (cell.Value + "          "); // do some thing                              
                }
            }
            data += System.Environment.NewLine;
            total += (int)row.Cells["TotPrice"].Value;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Please choose your invoice template", "Template");
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
    op.ShowHelp = true;
    op.Filter = "Microsoft Word Documents 97-2003 (*.doc)|*.doc|Microsoft Word 2007 (*.docx)|*.docx";
    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Please choose where you want to save the invoice", "Save");
    FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fd.Description = "Please choose";
    if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    string path = fd.SelectedPath + "\\" + txtFileName.Text + ".doc";

    CreateWordDoc(op.FileName, path);
}
```

Comment: Post the code you wrote please..

Comment: Which text file is it looking for, the original one, or the one that you supposedly saved? All of these actions are happening from one button that you're clicking twice?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might want to post some code.  Second of all, you should use the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) to save files instead of FolderBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this part

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"../../DatabasePath");
```

using an absolute path.
For example:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Here dir is main exe dir.
When you use OpenDialog current path could be changed, so you won't find your path again with **../../**.

Just another thing: when you use `Process.Start(@"..\..\DatabaseChooser.exe");` you wait for your process to be finished: I think you could do better if you create a `Process ps` and use `ps.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: Hi Marco, its still not working. When i click the button the first time it works, when click the button again it tries to read the text file from my desktop and i set it to use an absolute path. Please helkp

Comment: i have used this line of code, string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);, and it works the first time around but when i click the button again it tries to read the file from the desktop.

Comment: @Jason: I'm away now, but this evening I gonna help ypu. be patient :)

Comment: Hi Marco...i would really like to thank you for your help. I have solved the problem, with the help of that one line of code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are having trouble with:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"../../DatabasePath");
```

Change it to:

```
File f = new File(@"../../DatabasePath");
```

Then do a f.GetAbsolutePath to find out where it is actually getting the file.

A few more comments:

```
if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
  this.Hide();                    
}
```

If the user hits cancel the code is still going to attempt to run. And try to CreateWordDoc.